# implementing de castlejau algorithm c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphics

The program runs but the curved line isn't being displayed .
Here is my code and note, I have 4 vertices in an array.

```
void GLWidget::drawControlPolygon(){
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size()-1;i++){
        drawEdge(vertices[i], vertices[i+1], RGBValue(0,0,0));
    }
}

void GLWidget::drawDeCasteljau(float t) {

    Point p;
    int N_PTS = 4;

    p.x = pow((1-t),3)*vertices[0].x+3* t * pow((1 -t), 2) * vertices[1].x + 3 * (1-t)*pow(t,2)*vertices[2].x+ pow (t, 3)*vertices[3].x;
    p.y = pow((1-t),3)*vertices[0].y+3* t * pow((1 -t), 2) * vertices[1].y + 3 * (1-t)*pow(t,2)*vertices[2].y+ pow (t, 3)*vertices[3].y;
    p.z = pow((1-t),3)*vertices[0].z+3* t * pow((1 -t), 2) * vertices[1].z + 3 * (1-t)*pow(t,2)*vertices[2].z+ pow (t, 3)*vertices[3].z;

    int bezPoints[3][3] ;

    for (float u = 0.0; u <= 1.0; u += t) {
        for (int diag = N_PTS-2; diag >= 0; diag--) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= diag; i++) {
                int j = diag - i;
                bezPoints[i][j] = (1.0-u)*bezPoints[i][j+1] + u*bezPoints[i+1][j];
            }
        }
        // set the pixel for this parameter value

//Set pixel method for theImage object.
//        void setPixel(Index row, Index col, Byte red, Byte green, Byte blue, Byte alpha=255);
//        void setPixel(Index row, Index col, RGBValue colour, Byte alpha = 255);
                theImage.setPixel(bezPoints[0], bezPoints[0][0], RGBValue());

    }

}
void GLWidget::drawBezierCurve() {

}
```

for the full class here is the link to it...
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j6jw51uhz30m3tb/testApp.cc?dl=0

So far the output looks like this 
[image: current output]

Thanks!

Comment: You never initialise `bezPoints`. Its values are indeterminate, and using them is undefined. Also, did you intend to use `p` for anything?

Comment: your setPixel-method has wrong parameter i guess

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm not sure what the bezPoints are supposed to be I added them there because I will need to fill the bezPoints with something but I don't know what ill need to fill it with.